How to get last N items from dict?
I have a dict like this:
dict_ = {
   'abc': 1,
   'bcd': 2,
   'cde': 3,
   'def': 4
}

I need to iterate only last N items in dict with for k, v in dict.items(), how to do that? If that was list, I could do dict_[-N:], what about dict? Speed is important, so option about iterating all list in for loop with continue is not good.

If "the last N items" is a meaningful concept for your data, then a dict probably wasn't the appropriate way to store it in the first place.  A list of tuples, for example, could easily be indexed starting at N from the end.

"iterating all list in for loop" — what's that? Post code?

Since python 3.8 dictionaries are reversible, so you should be able to efficiently get at the end of the dict iterator. It's not clear if this is helpful since we don't know if n is really large or if the order of the last n items matter (the last n items of the reversed dict will be in the wrong order).

If speed is important, then so is the information about how large your dict and N are.

Does the order matter? Or only that it's the last N?

On modern versions of Python, you want something like:
from itertools import islice
last_n_items = list(islice(reversed(my_dict.items()), n))

You may want to reverse that one more time at the end.

@juanpa.arrivillaga's answer is good but the result needs to be reversed again to be equivalent to list(dict_)[-n:].
You can use a collections.deque with its extendleft method instead to store the result so that the resulting sequence would be in the expected order:
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque

last_n_items = deque()
last_n_items.extendleft(islice(reversed(dict_.items()), n))


That's a nice way to deal with the reversed results.

You could also do it like this:
n = 3
dict_items = list(data.items())[-n:]
new_dict_ = dict(last_n_items)

or:
n = 3
n_items = deque(data.items(), maxlen=n)
new_dict_ = dict(last_n_items)

